# Write to file from dictionary instead of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, writetofile

I would like to print dictionaries to file in a different way.
Right now, I am using Pandas to convert dictionaries to Dataframes, combine several Dataframes and then print them to file (see below code). 
However, the Pandas operations seem to take a very long time and I would like to do this more efficiently.

**Is it possible to do the below approach more efficiently while retaining the structure of the output files?** (e.g. by printing from dictionary directly?)

```
import pandas as pd

labels = ["A", "B", "C"]
periods = [0, 1, 2]
header = ['key', 'scenario', 'metric', 'labels']
metrics_names = ["metric_balances", "metric_record"]

key = "key_x"
scenario = "base"
# The metrics are structured as dicts where the keys are `periods` and the values 
# are arrays (where each array entry correspond to one of the `labels`)
metric_balances = {0: [1000, 100, 50], 1: [900, 150, 100], 2: [800, 350, 100]}
metric_record = {0: [20, 10, 5], 1: [90, 15, 10], 2: [80, 35, 10]}

# Combine all metrics into one output structure for key "x"
output_x = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(metric_balances, columns=periods, index=labels),
                      pd.DataFrame(metric_record, columns=periods, index=labels)],
                     keys=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[key], [scenario], metrics_names]), 
                     names=header)

key = "key_y"
scenario = "base_2"
metric_balances = {0: [2000, 200, 50], 1: [1900, 350, 100], 2: [1200, 750, 100]}
metric_record = {0: [40, 5, 3], 1: [130, 45, 10], 2: [82, 25, 18]}

# Combine all metrics into one output structure for key "y"
output_y = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(metric_balances, columns=periods, index=labels),
                      pd.DataFrame(metric_record, columns=periods, index=labels)],
                     keys=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[key], [scenario], metrics_names]), 
                     names=header)

# Concatenate all output dataframes
output = pd.concat([output_x, output_y], names=header)
# Print results to a csv file
output.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)
```

Below are the respective outputs:

```
OUTPUT X
                                           0    1    2
key    scenario metric          labels                
key_x  base     metric_balances A       1000  900  800
                                B        100  150  350
                                C         50  100  100
                metric_record   A         20   90   80
                                B         10   15   35
                                C          5   10   10

-----------------------------------
OUTPUT Y
                                           0     1     2
key    scenario metric          labels                  
key_y  base_2   metric_balances A       2000  1900  1200
                                B        200   350   750
                                C         50   100   100
                metric_record   A         40   130    82
                                B          5    45    25
                                C          3    10    18

------------------------------
OUTPUT COMBINED
                                           0     1     2
key    scenario metric          labels                  
key_x  base     metric_balances A       1000   900   800
                                B        100   150   350
                                C         50   100   100
                metric_record   A         20    90    80
                                B         10    15    35
                                C          5    10    10
key_y  base_2   metric_balances A       2000  1900  1200
                                B        200   350   750
                                C         50   100   100
                metric_record   A         40   130    82
                                B          5    45    25
                                C          3    10    18
```

I was looking into row wise printing of the dictionaries - but I had difficulties in merging the `labels` with the relevant arrays.